# DBDelta not creating table wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

Db delta doesn't seem to create the table when I checked it from my PHPMyAdmin.

PS: I don't write php or wordpress plugins, this is the first time.

Please Help.

Here's my code:

```
$dbname = 'wordpress_auth';
function activate_auth() {
    global $wpdb;
                    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

                    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$dbname` (
                      userid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                      authsecret varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY  (userid)
                    ) $charset_collate;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'activate_auth');
```

Comment: Where have you defined $dbname ?

Comment: Yes it is defined just above the function.

Comment: Add it to the code in your question.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz done!

Comment: If you are beginner with WordPress, you can explain what you want to do and we can give you advices to not create a new table but use the   functions of wordpress

Comment: I'm a node.js programmer and I've been using (not programming) wordpress for quite a while and I'm try to create a new table where I can store some authentication codes where the userid is the primary key and that identifies the wordpress admin id which is an integer  and also the authsecret which is a string.

Comment: The $dbname  variable needs to be declared within the function.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz thanks :)